# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a when setting -ObjC flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, static-libraries, armv7

I'm trying to link my iOS app project to a static library I built, and I'm following the instructions in [Using Static Libraries in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH3-SW1). This project already links `Google Analytics` library, `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a`, which was working fine, but when I set the `-ObjC` flag in the target's build settings for my static library, I'm not able to build it anymore. I get "Apple Mach-O Linker Errors" saying `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7` in `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` and which point to things such as "_sqlite3_column_bytes".

Has somebody experienced this? How could I solve it?

Thanks

**Note:** I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 and my deployment target is iOS 7.0

Comment: Check if you have added libs and libSql library in framework section.

Comment: @iOSWeblineindia I don't find any `libSql`in Build Phases, and I'm not directly linking `libsqlite3.dylib` since I'm using Core Data

Comment: Yes, but that library might required by GA SDK. Can you please add it and try to build. And Yes other one is libz and not libs.

Comment: @iOSWeblineindia ok, looks like adding `libsqlite3.dylib` removes the errors... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @iOSWeblineindia, I solved this issue by adding `libsqlite3.dylib` in Build Phases

Answer (score 0):

You have to include:

```
CoreData.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
```

[Google analytics devguides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#headers) is a link to documentation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have those, since I already had `Google Analytics` working before setting the -ObjC flag